# Apache 2.4.9 Pseudo Streaming

Tags: apache, apache2.4, pseudo-streaming

Im aware of [this](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac) however, this appears to only work for apache 2.2.x. I'm looking for something like this for 2.4.9.

I've done quite a bit of googleing already and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason I couldn't get the module to work my initial go around (I tried more than once). However, I got it to work today.

Not sure what I did different but I just followed the instructions below (again).

http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Apache-Version2